# Error when trying to import npm package (easyMDE) in application.js - (Uncaught ReferenceError: EasyMDE is not defined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, webpacker

Im trying to include [easyMDE](https://github.com/Ionaru/easy-markdown-editor) in my rails 6 project. I was including it from an external source before and that worked (via unpkg.com). To improve loading times I wanted to include it into my project via yarn.

---

I did the following steps:

```
 yarn add easymde --save
```

In **application.js**:

```
require("easymde");
```

But when reloading the page I get the following error:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: EasyMDE is not defined
```

When I run webpack-dev-server I see that easymde.js gets compiled:

```
Built at: 08/11/2020 3:16:09 PM
                                 Asset       Size         Chunks                              Chunk Names
js/application-caadc00338c3578fee39.js       1.2 MiB      application  [emitted] [immutable]  application
js/application-caadc00338c3578fee39.js.map   1.39 MiB     application  [emitted] [dev]        application
js/easymde-1f6737d8a160c1180536.js           872 KiB      easymde      [immutable]            easymde
js/easymde-1f6737d8a160c1180536.js.map       805 KiB      easymde      [dev]                  easymde
                         manifest.json       675 bytes                 [emitted]              
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

---

**application.js**:

```js
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
 
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

require("easymde")
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "logbook_v2",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "easymde": "^2.11.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

---

Let me know if you need any more code. :-)

---

---

**Update**

Here is the file where I use the editor:

```
<%= render "components/sidebar" %>
<div class="form-wrapper post-form-wrapper">
  <%= form_with model: @post, class: 'form post-form' do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'title', class: 'field post-field' %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, id: 'mde' %>
    <%= f.submit 'create post', class: 'form-button post-form-button' %>
  <%end%>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var easyMDE = new EasyMDE({
        element: document.getElementById("mde"),
        placeholder: "Write your post here...",
        autosave: {
            enabled: true,
            uniqueId: <%= current_user.id %>
        },
        blockStyles: {
            code: "~~~"
        },
        minHeight: "calc(100vh - 320px)",
        renderingConfig: {
            codeSyntaxHighlighting: true
        },
        promptURLs: true,
        toolbar: ["bold", "italic", "strikethrough", "heading", "|", "code", "quote", "clean-block", "|", "link", "image", "|", "unordered-list", "ordered-list", "|", "preview", "side-by-side", "fullscreen", "|", "guide"]
    });
</script>
```

If I put in `import * as EasyMDE from 'easymde';` (suggested by @Ninh Le) at the beginning of the script I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Easymde` using `module.exports`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/Ionaru/easy-markdown-editor/blob/master/src/js/easymde.js#L2777)
So to use it in with yarn and rails 6 I think the way is in js file:

```js
import * as EasyMDE from 'easymde';
var easyMDE = new EasyMDE({element: document.getElementById('my-text-area')});
```

Edit: To make it can call globally, call this in application.js file

```js
import * as EasyMDE from 'easymde';
window.EasyMDE = EasyMDE;
```

Comment: Where do I have to put `import * as EasyMDE from 'easymde';`? I tried it in **application.js** but still the same error.

Comment: hmm, where did you use EasyMDE, I think you should import in this file, I have made a simple test with `console.log(easyMDE)` it works fine

Comment: I have tested in application.js file and code looks like [this](https://pastebin.pl/view/198f7fae)

Comment: I eddited the post and included the file where I use the editor.

Comment: I see you embed javascript in the view file, why not move it into separate javascript file and then include js file into view?

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: If you want to import it in application.js you can try by adding `window.EasyMDE = EasyMDE;` after import but I'm not sure this is best practice cuz you can access anywhere

Comment: Putting `import * as EasyMDE from 'easymde';` and `window.EasyMDE = EasyMDE;` into **application.js** worked. If you edit your answer and include that step I can mark it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have edited, if you can mark my answer, thank you :D